# Blackberry not creating a valid sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

I have a very unusual problem.

I'm trying to create a simple database (6 tables, 4 of which only have 2 columns).
I'm using an in-house database library which I've used in a previous project, and it does work.

However with my current project there are *occasional* bugs. Basically the database isn't created correctly. It is added to the sdcard but when I access it I get a `DatabaseException`.

When I access the device from the desktop manager and try to open the database (with SQLite Database Browser v2.0b1) I get "File is not a SQLite 3 database".

**UPDATE**
I found that this happens when I delete the database manually off the sdcard.
Since there's no way to stop a user doing that, is there anything I can do to handle it?

**CODE**

```
public static boolean initialize()
{
    boolean memory_card_available = ApplicationInterface.isSDCardIn();
    String application_name = ApplicationInterface.getApplicationName();
    if (memory_card_available == true)
    {
        file_path = "file:///SDCard/" + application_name + ".db";
    }
    else
    {
        file_path = "file:///store/" + application_name + ".db";
    }

    try
    {
        uri = URI.create(file_path);
        FileClass.hideFile(file_path);
    } catch (MalformedURIException mue)
    {
    }

    return create(uri);
}

private static boolean create(URI db_file)
{
    boolean response = false;

    try
    {
        db = DatabaseFactory.create(db_file);
        db.close();

        response = true;
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like your problem is that the user is deleting your database, just make sure to catch exceptions when you open it (or access it ... wherever you're getting the exception):

```java
try {
    URI uri = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/database1.db");
    sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);
    Statement st = sqliteDB.createStatement( "CREATE TABLE 'Employee' ( " +
                                              "'Name' TEXT, " +
                                              "'Age' INTEGER )" );               
    st.prepare();
    st.execute();
} catch ( DatabaseException e ) {         
    System.out.println( e.getMessage() );

    // TODO: decide if you want to create a new database here, or 
    // alert the user if the SDCard is not available
}
```

Note that even though it's probably unusual for a user to **delete** a private file that your app creates, it's perfectly normal for the SDCard to be unavailable because the device is connected to a PC via USB.  So, you really should always be testing for this condition (file open error).

[See this answer regarding checking for SDCard availability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9272878/119114).

Also, [read this about SQLite db storage locations](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/SQLite_database_files_1219778_11.jsp), and make sure to [review this answer by Michael Donohue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4451954/119114) about eMMC storage.

---

### Update: SQLite Corruption

[See this link describing the many ways SQLite databases can be corrupted](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html).  It definitely sounded to me like maybe the .db file was deleted, but not the journal / wal file.  If that was it, you could try deleting `database1*` programmatically before you create `database1.db`.  But, your comments seem to suggest that it was something else.  Perhaps you could look into the file locking failure modes, too.

If you are desperate, you might try changing your code to use a different name (e.g. `database2`, `database3`) each time you create a new db, to make sure you're not getting artifacts from the previous db.

Comment: Thanks nate, I'll have a look at those links. The problem however isn't that the database is not created, it's that the file is created incorrectly. Appears on the file system, but not a valid database file.

Comment: I thought your update said that the problem is that the user is manually deleting the file after your app creates it?  Did I misunderstand that part?

Comment: Oh, sorry if I'm being confusing. I can create a db fine. If I delete it from the sdcard, then next time I run the app it does not create the db correctly.

Comment: I think you'd need to show the code you're using, if this is still a problem.

Comment: Hi Nate, I have just added the code I'm using to create the db

Comment: @Kevin, and you get a `DatabaseException` on the `DatabaseFactory.create()` line; and only when you try to create a new db, **after** the user has manually deleted a previous db (at the same file location)?

Comment: Hi nate, thanks for the quick reply. I don't get any exceptions when creating. The exceptions occur when trying to use the db.    
After manually deleting the db, it is created incorrectly by the app. The exception is then caused by accessing the faulty db file

Comment: @Kevin, are you just mounting the SDCard on your PC, and then deleting it with a normal file explorer application?  Which OS does your PC run? Also, if the database is named `database1.db`, then do you see any other files being created on the SDCard named `database1.*`?  Same name, but with different file extension?

Comment: File explorer: yes. OS: windows 8. Extra file: No. there was something like `database1-journal` at one stage. Its not there now.

Comment: @Kevin, can you verify that you **can** reproduce the problem, but that you don't necessarily see the journal file there?  Make sure that when you look in your explorer window, do a refresh and make sure there's no setting hiding certain file extensions.  Be confident that you really **only** see the `database1.db` file.  Thanks.

Comment: I have just reproduced it. The journal file is not there. I'm also showing all hidden files, and its not there either. Only `database1.db` is there

Comment: Ok, so after that, the app's next attempt to create, then **access** the database fails?  If that's the case, I might be out of ideas.  I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Yeah, its troubling. Since there's way to actually stop a user from doing it (no matter how unlikely it is). Thanks for the attempt though, I appreciate it

Comment: @Kevin, You're welcome.  Take a look at the last section I posted in my update above.  It might help you figure out what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

My only suggestion is keep a default database in your assets - if there is a problem with the one on the SD Card, attempt to recreate it by copying the default one.

Not a very good answer I expect.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Never really thought of that